# Deleting a first node in the linked list or pop in the queue

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

My program triggers a breakpoint, and I think that the algorythm is good. I want to delete the first node in the linked list, or a queue, whatever. The point is that I can normally add elements to the stack, but can't remove them as it triggers a breakpoint. Why? I would like to remove the first element without using front and back pointers. Is that possible?
My code:

```html
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<time.h>

    #define MAX 100
    #define MIN 10

    typedef struct node* Queue;

    struct node {
        int el;
        Queue next;
    };

    void push(int x, Queue S);
    void pop(Queue S);
    void show(Queue S);


    int main() {
        int sl;
        char c;

        struct node Head;
        Head.next = NULL;

        srand(time(0));

        while (1) {
            printf("Queue\n\t->D to push\n\t->I to pop\n\t\n\t->E for exit\n\t->Choice: ");
            scanf("%c", &c);
            switch (c) {
            case'd':
            case'D':
                sl = MIN + rand() % ((MAX - MIN) + 1);
                push(sl, &Head);
                show(Head.next);
                break;
            case'i':
            case'I':
                pop(&Head);
                printf("After pop:\n");
                show(Head.next);
                break;
            case'e':
            case'E':
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("A mistake has occured.\n");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
      void push(int x, Queue S) {
        Queue q;
        q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        q->el = x;
        q->next = S->next;
        S->next = q;
    }

    void pop(Queue S) {
    Queue temp,pre;
    temp = S->next;
    pre=NULL;
    while(temp && temp->next) {
        pre = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    free(pre->next);
    pre->next = NULL;
}
    void show(Queue S) {
        while (S != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", S->el);
            S = S->next;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are pushing elements you are doing at the `Head->next` ,but `pop` ing is done from `Head`, that an invalid address and you see problem.

Note : I have not handled pointer `NULL` checks, better to do those when you try `next` of any pointers

```
void pop(Queue S) {
    Queue temp;
    temp = S->next;
    //S = S->next;
    S->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
}
```

to delete the first inserted element you will have to traverse this list and make note of `previous` pointer as used here by variable `pre` and when you reach last element(which is the one inserted first) delete it using `pre` pointer.

```
void pop(Queue S) {
    Queue temp,pre = NULL;
    temp = S->next;
    while(temp && temp->next) {
        pre = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(pre) {
        free(pre->next);
        pre->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

But, I strongly advice you to follow the rules of Stack(LIFO) and Queue(FIFO).

In queue the insertion is done at rear end and deletion is done at front end, so use the pointers accordingly and implement.

Comment: That is a regular stack using LIFO, but I want FIFO algorythm.

Comment: then you have to modify your `pop` function because it currently deletes what is latest, to do what you want you have to traverse to last element and delete

Comment: Can you help me figure it out please @IrAM

Comment: I can't figure it out how to make that exact code in that function because nothing works

Comment: @JackJones, try to understand the program.

Comment: I understand the program, it adds nodes at the end of the list, but this function you wrote removes the lastest node.

Comment: edited code will not compile. Compiler says that potetionally unintialized local pointer variable 'pre' used for some reason.

Comment: **_but I want FIFO algorythm_** this is what you said before, first inserted element will be deleted by using the second snippet of the code, as for the error for `pre` , make `pre=NULL`

Comment: I made pre=NULL, now it gives me 1 unresolved externals error. @IrAM

Comment: please edit you post with changes and update the code, so that i can see error

Comment: Your code works like a charm sir! But only until the list has elements. When it is empty it gives me an error that pre is nullptr, something like that. I have yet to figure that out. PS I solved the error, my pop function had different names because I was translating function names back and forth (my code is not in English).

Comment: I edited my code, but can you just help me with that little thing and I will put your answer as a solution to this problem. I tried with if(pre!=NULL) free(pre->next);

Comment: yes plz put both the statements in `if` block,  updated the answer for ref

Comment: It works now like a charm :D thank you so much man, I appreciate it much!